# Redirect URI - Local host refusing connection

Tags: redirect, localhost, soundcloud

I'm intending to work with Soundcloud for a project. I'm using:

'http://localhost/soundcloud/oauth-callback.html'

for my redirect_uri which gives me a Connect with Soundcloud prompt to allow “myProject” access to my account?

Every time I click to connect to Soundcloud my localhost refuses. There are no log errors. How do I resolve this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the app settings for "myProject" on soundcloud and there you can enter the redirect_uri for your site.

```
http://localhost/soundcloud/oauth-callback.html
```

And in the JS it should be your matching URL, eg.

```
redirect_uri: "http://localhost/soundcloud/oauth-callback.html"
```